# Create a new dictionary from a nested JSON output after parsing

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python3 I need to get a JSON response from an API call,
and parse it so I will get a dictionary That only contains the data I need.
The final dictionary I ecxpt to get is as follows:

```
{'Severity Rules': ('cc55c459-eb1a-11e8-9db4-0669bdfa776e', ['cc637182-eb1a-11e8-9db4-0669bdfa776e']), 'auto_collector': ('57e9a4ec-21f7-4e0e-88da-f0f1fda4c9d1', ['0ab2470a-451e-11eb-8856-06364196e782'])}
```

the JSON response returns the following output:

```
{
    'RuleGroups': [{
        'Id': 'cc55c459-eb1a-11e8-9db4-0669bdfa776e',
        'Name': 'Severity Rules',
        'Order': 1,
        'Enabled': True,
        'Rules': [{
            'Id': 'cc637182-eb1a-11e8-9db4-0669bdfa776e',
            'Name': 'Severity Rule',
            'Description': 'Look for default severity text',
            'Enabled': False,
            'RuleMatchers': None,
            'Rule': '\\b(?P<severity>DEBUG|TRACE|INFO|WARN|ERROR|FATAL|EXCEPTION|[I|i]nfo|[W|w]arn|[E|e]rror|[E|e]xception)\\b',
            'SourceField': 'text',
            'DestinationField': 'text',
            'ReplaceNewVal': '',
            'Type': 'extract',
            'Order': 21520,
            'KeepBlockedLogs': False
        }],
        'Type': 'user'
    }, {
        'Id': '4f6fa7c6-d60f-49cd-8c3d-02dcdff6e54c',
        'Name': 'auto_collector',
        'Order': 4,
        'Enabled': True,
        'Rules': [{
            'Id': '2d6bdc1d-4064-11eb-8856-06364196e782',
            'Name': 'auto_collector',
            'Description': 'DO NOT CHANGE!! Created via API coralogix-blocker tool',
            'Enabled': False,
            'RuleMatchers': None,
            'Rule': 'AUTODISABLED',
            'SourceField': 'subsystemName',
            'DestinationField': 'subsystemName',
            'ReplaceNewVal': '',
            'Type': 'block',
            'Order': 1,
            'KeepBlockedLogs': False
        }],
        'Type': 'user'
    }]
}
```

I was able to create a dictionary that contains the name and the RuleGroupsID, like that:

```
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
output = response.json()
outputlist=(output["RuleGroups"])
groupRuleName = [li['Name'] for li in outputlist]
groupRuleID = [li['Id'] for li in outputlist]
# Create a dictionary of NAME + ID
ruleDic = {}
for key in groupRuleName:
    for value in groupRuleID:
        ruleDic[key] = value
        groupRuleID.remove(value)
        break
```

Which gave me a simple dictionary:

```
{'Severity Rules': 'cc55c459-eb1a-11e8-9db4-0669bdfa776e', 'Rewrites': 'ddbaa27e-1747-11e9-9db4-0669bdfa776e', 'Extract': '0cb937b6-2354-d23a-5806-4559b1f1e540', 'auto_collector': '4f6fa7c6-d60f-49cd-8c3d-02dcdff6e54c'}
```

but when I tried to parse it as nested JSON things just didn't work.

Comment: You need to see where in the response the json return , is it in response.text? any way i wouldn't convert it to list ,and looping over it in the following for keys,values in output .items()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I managed to create a function that returns this dictionary,
I'm doing it by breaking the JSON into 3 lists by the needed elements (which are **Name**, **Id**,   and **Rules** from the first nest), and then create another list from the nested JSON ( which listed everything under **Rule**) which only create a list from the keyword "**Id**".

Finally creating a dictionary using a zip command on the lists and dictionaries created earlier.

```
def get_filtered_rules() -> List[dict]:
    groupRuleName = [li['Name'] for li in outputlist]
    groupRuleID = [li['Id'] for li in outputlist]
    ruleIDList = [li['Rules'] for li in outputlist]
    ruleIDListClean = []
    ruleClean = []
    for sublist in ruleIDList:
        try:
            lstRule = [item['Rule'] for item in sublist]
            ruleClean.append(lstRule)
            ruleContent=list(zip(groupRuleName, ruleClean))
            ruleContentDictionary = dict(ruleContent)
            lstID = [item['Id'] for item in sublist]
            ruleIDListClean.append(lstID)
            # Create a dictionary of NAME + ID + RuleID
            ruleDic = dict(zip(groupRuleName, zip(groupRuleID, ruleIDListClean)))
        except Exception as e: print(e)
    return ruleDic
```